# Specialization of an irreducible polynomial and monogeneous ring of integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $P\in\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\ldots,X_n][T]$ be an irreducible polynomial, which is monic in $T$ of degree $d\geq 1$.

For $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{Q}^n$, let $P_x=P(x_1,\ldots,x_n,T)$.

It is well-known that there the set $U$ of $x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $P_x$ is irreducible is Zariski dense. For $x\in U$, let $\alpha_x\in\mathbb{C}$ be any root of $P_x$.

**Question.** Can we choose $x\in U$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(a\alpha_x)(=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_x))$ is $\mathbb{Z}[a\alpha_x]$ ?

In fact, it is known that $U\cap\mathbb{Z}^n$ is infinite, so another variant of the question would be:

**Question'.** If $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_n][T]$ (and satisfies the assumptions above), can we choose $x\in U \cap\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_x)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_x]$ ?

I have no intuition whatsoever of what the answer could be.

I know that the answer is **yes** for the generic polynomial $T^d+X_{d-1}T^{d-1}+\cdots+X_1T+X_0$ (take $x=(rad(d),0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{Z}^d$, where $rad(d)$ is the product of the distinct prime divisors of $d$)

I really doubt the answer is **yes** in general, but I would be extremely happy if it actually is.

Of course, I have a specific polynomial $P$ in mind: let $B\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ be a symmetric matrix with nonzero determinant, and let $N=(X_{ij})_{i,j}$ with $X_{ij}=X_{ji}$ for all $i,j$ the generic symmetric matrix. Then $P_B=\det(T I_n-BN)$ is irreducible. Any answer to the question for $P_B$ would be helpful.

Greg